# Unity vs iOS and for loops not executing the same way?

Tags: c#, ios, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I am trying to produce an scrolling list based on how many games a user has active. It works just fine in Unity editor but for some reason it is not working the same way when build to an iOS unit?

Here is what I am doing:

```
int i = 0;

Debug.Log ("1. The myturn count: "+myturn.Count);

List<ParseObject> myturnList = new List<ParseObject>(myturn.Values);
myturnList.Sort((e1,e2) => e1.Get<string>("lastMoveTime").CompareTo(e2.Get<string>("lastMoveTime")));

Debug.Log ("2. The myturnlist count: "+myturnList.Count);

for(int x = 0;x <= myturnList.Count;x++){
    if(x == myturnList.Count){
        ActiveGames[i].SetActive(true);
        MoreGamesSpacer(i);
        i++;
    } else {
        ActiveGames[i].SetActive(true);
        GameLogic(myturnList[i],i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

In the Unity editor the 2 Debug.logs comes out with the number 4, but in the iOS unit it comes out with zero? in both cases it produces the list, but as you can see from the script it should produce the 4 games before the "MoreGames" in the list. In Unity correct, but on iOS the "MoreGames" comes first and then the games?!?!?

Is there something I am missing in regards to for loops and iOS or what?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: check weather "myturn.Count" is zero in ios. If it is then will start with i = 0  and will run till i is equal to "myturnList.Count" which is same as "myturn.Count" which if it is zero then it will run once and your first condition will get satisfied with "MoreGames". Pls check what output "myturn.Count" gives in IOS.

Comment: @killer_mech - myturn.Count comes out as zero in iOS but not in Unity. The strange thing is that it still generates the 4 gameitems but after the the "MoreGames" item, so for some reason the myturn is holding 4 objects but not counting them in iOS?

Comment: can you give the details of what MoreGamesSpacer(i); and GameLogic(myturnList[i],i); these function do?

Comment: They build a list item (gameobject), so if there is 4 games it should build / instantiate these 4 gameobjects and then the MoreGamesSpacer.